# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" is occured by setting variables in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing homework that compressing the string.

for example, 1111 -> 1, 2222 -> 2, 11112222 -> (12)

The first thing to check for is duplicate strings.

If the strings are all the same, you only need to represent one character, or you need the same process as above.

So I wrote the code like this:

```
s = "1111"

s = "11112222"

result = s[0] 
half = int(len(s)/2)

lstr = s[0:half]
rstr = s[half:]

lans = lstr[0]
rans = rstr[0]

for i in range(len(s)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[j]:
            ans = s[0]
            continue

        else:
```

This is valid for "1111", but an error occurs for "11112222".

TypeError: string indices must be integers

I had searched on the internet but I think it is ok.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution and aren't specifically interested in why this error is occurring, I would simply use sets.

```
s = '1111'
s2 = '11112222'

ans = (''.join(x for x in set(s)))
ans2 = (''.join(x for x in set(s2)))

print(ans, ans2)
```

Will print 1 12

Comment: Additionally, I can't replicate this error using your posted code. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Thanks for replying. the error was occured  if s[i] == s[j]: TypeError: string indices must be integers. But it's only occured in case of '11112222'.colud you tell me how to solve this problem?